# Multiply dataframes with similar index but unequal levels

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes as follows

df1

```
Location  Month  Date  Ratio
A         June   Jun 1  0.2
A         June   Jun 2  0.3
A         June   Jun 3  0.4
B         June   Jun 1  0.6
B         June   Jun 2  0.7
B         June   Jun 3  0.8
```

And df2

```
Location  Month   Value
A         June    1000
B         June    2000
```

Result should be as :
df3

```
Location  Month  Date   Value
A         June   Jun 1  200
A         June   Jun 2  300
A         June   Jun 3  400
B         June   Jun 1  1200
B         June   Jun 2  1400
B         June   Jun 3  1600
```

How do I go about doing this. I am able to carry out division without problem as Pandas somehow does great job of matching indices while division but in multiplication result is all over the place.

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Location` index for both?

Comment: Yes the indices match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`df.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)

```
 df.assign(Value = df.merge(df1,how='inner',on=['Location','Month'])['Value'].\
                      mul(df['Ratio']))

#or
# df = df.merge(df1,how='inner',on=['Location','Month'])
# df['Value']*=df['Ratio']

  Location Month   Date  Ratio   Value
0        A  June  Jun 1    0.2   200.0
1        A  June  Jun 2    0.3   300.0
2        A  June  Jun 3    0.4   400.0
3        B  June  Jun 1    0.6  1200.0
4        B  June  Jun 2    0.7  1400.0
5        B  June  Jun 3    0.8  1600.0
```

Or
using [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

```
df.set_index(['Location','Month'],inplace=True)
df1.set_index(['Location','Month'],inplace=True)

df['Value'] = df['Ratio']*df1['Value']
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC and `Location` is index for both dataframe then you can use [`pandas.Series.mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html)

```
df1["Value"] = df1.Ratio.mul(df2.Value)
df1
         Month   Date  Ratio   Value
Location
A         June  Jun 1    0.2   200.0
A         June  Jun 2    0.3   300.0
A         June  Jun 3    0.4   400.0
B         June  Jun 1    0.6  1200.0
B         June  Jun 2    0.7  1400.0
B         June  Jun 3    0.8  1600.0
```